# Why is optical orbital angular momentum (OAM) called "topological charge"?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, optics, quantum-information, topology

The terminology "topological charge" is frequent in lots of research papers related to optical vortex or optical OAM, it is used to represent the optical OAM. Why? How to comprehend it?

Answer (score 2):

Basically it means that in the case of OAM=0 the wave fronts make a structure similar to a stack of plates, and in the case of OAM=1 they make a helix-like structure, and 1 refers to the helix multiplicity (for a double helix it would be 2 and so on). One cannot be changed to the other continuously, so this is a topological feature. There are other topological charges in the theory of fields, but in optics it is usually nothing deeper than that.

Comment: Something else to point out is that the topological charge can be positive and negative and also adds up like electrical charge.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The "adding up" stuff would take rather extensive explanation with figures, I'm afraid. I feel not qualified enough to write it down. Maybe you would write it in your own answer?

Comment: You say "One cannot be changed to the other continuously", could you explain why this is a topological feature? I dont know about "topological", and this terminology seems to be hard to understand. Thanks.